# Выделение памяти для одинаковых по значению примитивов

Tags: java

Как Java выделяет память, если объявить:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 10;
```

Верно ли я понимаю, что переменная `b` будет просто новой ссылкой на тот же участок памяти, на который указывает переменная `a`?

Comment: Нет, каждой переменной будет выделен свой участок стека, а каждому полю свой участок объекта в куче.

Comment: А можно ткнуть в первоисточник?

Comment: Это поведение не оговоренное в спецификации, на сколько я помню. Поэтому, во-первых, поведение виртуальной машины соответствует семантике кода, а во-вторых, единственный подтверждающий это источник - [исходный код JVM](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, не верно.

`int` - примитивный тип. Есть ссылочный тип `Integer`, [статья](https://habr.com/post/104231/) на Habr.

Две ссылки на один объект будут у двух ссылочных переменных типа `String`, допустим, если сделать так:

```
String s1 = "s1";
String s2 = s1;
```

Есть [хорошая статья](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) на wiki про типы переменных, есть [статья](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/3.13.php) про конкретно ссылочные типы и их содержание в памяти.

Comment: Да и не стоит рассчитывать на гарантированное интернирование строковых объектов, так как это деталь реализации HotSpot, не оговоренная в JLS. К тому же пул очень маленький.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev т.е., может быть вероятность, что будут разные ссылки на разные объекты?

Comment: Может быть, может не быть. Пока не занимаешься оптимизацией в красной зоне, лучше не писать код делающий какие-либо допущения.